# Crash for didReceiveRemoteNotification and iOS 14

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios14

I have a specific crash for iOS14 only. My code has not changed for a long time and there were no issues on all previous versions of iOS, but according to Crashlytics I see this stacktrace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x19125b7f4 <redacted> + 36
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1912298c4 dispatch_group_leave + 126
2  MyApp                          0x104e2c72c partial apply for closure #1 in AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) + 4375054124 (<compiler-generated>:4375054124)
3  MyApp                          0x104e2b488 closure #1 in closure #2 in AppDelegate.configureNotificationReceipt(userInfo:completionHandler:) + 194 (AppDelegate.swift:194)
4  MyApp                          0x104e48d78 closure #1 in closure #1 in static AWSController.downloadFile(with:completion:) + 37 (AWSController.swift:37)
5  MyApp                          0x104e5d794 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4375254932 (<compiler-generated>:4375254932)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x191226fd0 <redacted> + 32
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x191228ac8 <redacted> + 20
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x19123604c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1915a71e4 <redacted> + 16
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1915a13b4 <redacted> + 2508
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1915a04bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
12 GraphicsServices               0x1a8025820 GSEventRunModal + 164
13 UIKitCore                      0x193f44734 <redacted> + 1072
14 UIKitCore                      0x193f49e10 UIApplicationMain + 168
15 MyApp                          0x104e16e30 main + 17 (AppCoordinator.swift:17)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x191267e60 <redacted> + 4
```

Also there is info from Crashlytics:

```
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave()
```

I use `Firebase/Messaging` for notifications. Also there is a code for handling of notification:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    configureNotificationReceipt(userInfo: userInfo) { (result) in
        completionHandler(result)
    }
}
```

As I wrote this crash is only for iOS14 and it was not there before. If we're speaking about `Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave()` I would say that it's related to internal logic of iOS maybe, because I don't work with GCD explicitly anywhere.

Perhaps someone has already encountered the same behavior and can suggest any workaround?

Comment: Is `completionHandler` always called? Meaning that  if `configureNotificationReceipt(userInfo:completion)` will always call the completion or you might have a special case where it isn't, AND maybe how much times would that take (since you only have 30 seconds).

Comment: @Larme yes, `completionHandler` is called always with `completionHandler(.newData)` or `completionHandler(.noData)`. Also right now I've add `completionHandler(.failed)` for error case. Could you share more info about 30 seconds? I have case when `completionHandler` can be called in a minute and a half and there were no issues (crashes) with this before. Is this iOS14 specific?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application It's in the doc. iOS14 might have been more respectful of that time, or changed "the error" kind, and it wasn't detected "as a crash"?

Comment: @Larme thanks, great! Sure, I'll fix business logic for it and change to max 30 seconds, but this logic worked from iOS8 and to iOS14, but now there is crash for new iOS version only:) Maybe somebody share any more ideas.

Comment: @Larme I've released new version of app with fixes. Unfortunately, the crash is repeated. As I wrote for iOS14 only. I guess need to wait an update of iOS from Apple.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using react-native with Expo SDK 36.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev do you have any solution/update on this?

Comment: @ManjuJK yes, I fixed it. My issue was that the completion handler was called twice and the second call crashed the app. I fixed it and don't know why it's related to iOS14 only. Also I'd recommend read [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3944)

Comment: PLEASE Answer your own question with this. I think people need to know!

Comment: @VadimNikolaev your solution fixed my issue as well. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think is Firebase iOS SDK issue, that is fixed on version 7.1.0.

Please refer links:

1. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/6863
2. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#7.1.0